# GNURADIO 3.10 : PlutoSDR (and all Industrial I/O) blocks missing?

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm new to Gnuradio and recently I wanted to use the software with a Adalm Pluto SDR, which rely on the `gr-iio` module.

According to the [3.10 gnuradio changelog](https://www.gnuradio.org/news/2022-01-17-gnuradio-v3.10.0.0-release/), [analog devices website](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-software/gnuradio) and Josh Morman [FOSDEM 2022 slides](https://archive.fosdem.org/2022/schedule/event/radio_gr3_10/attachments/slides/4996/export/events/attachments/radio_gr3_10/slides/4996/GR_3_10_FOSDEM_2022.pdf), now the `gr-iio` module is integrated in the gnuradio software (as well as the `gr-pdu`).

However, while I'm able to see the PDU tools in the available blocks in gnuradio companion, I cannot see any Industrial I/O related blocks.

In `/usr/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks`, there is no block that contain iio in their name.

My Gnu Radio Companion version is `3.10.9.2`, and I'm using fedora `40`

Do you have any idea on why I don't have those modules ? Do I need to install something else ?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Hugo

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Fedora 37 still, so things may be different but I just encountered the very same issue: `gr-iio` is missing.

It turns out that `gnuradio` looks for `libiio` and `libad9361-iio` during the compilatiaon process and includes `gr-iio` if these are found. In case they are missing, `gr-iio` is no built and is therefore missing from the rpm shipped by Fedora.

My solution was to install the two libraries and then to recompile and reinstall the `gnuradio` packages (`dnf download --source gnuradio`, `rpmbuild` and then install).

I don't feel comfortable submitting a bug report to Fedora since I'm on an old version, but I will do that when I upgrade if the problem persists. I don't know of an easy/clean way to install `gr-iio` separately from the gnuradio core unfortunately...